# In UNIX, how could you find a single word in a long string?

Tags: string, unix, awk, grep, cpu-word

Suppose I have the following string:

```
 mystring="something something something schwifty3 something"
```

now I know that theres a `schwifty` with a number after it, but I want the whole word from this string with everything else excluded.

`grep -o` does not appear to work or even be a useable option for some reason... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Translate the spaces into line breaks so that grep returns only single words.

```
mystring="something something something schwifty3 something"
echo "$mystring" | tr " " '\n' | grep "schwifty"
```

Comment: I will use this forever. Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

For a pure shell approach, the string substitution with prefix (#) and suffix (%) removal would work:

```
mystring="something something something schwifty3 something"

s=schwifty

case $mystring in 
(*$s*) 
    a="$s${mystring#*$s}"
    echo ${a%% *}
esac
```

This will show the first occurrence of any string starting with `$s` in `$mystring`.  Assumption: you split the string on an ascii space only.

The pure shell approach means that we just use shell builtins and mechanics, no external commands.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
grep -Po "schwifty\d" <<< $mystring
```

or this if there are maybe more than one digits in the string:

```
grep -Po "schwifty\d+" <<< $mystring
```

Answer (score 1):

-w for word in grep

```
echo sth sth something sth1|sed 's/ /\n/g'|grep -w sth
sth
sth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo $mystring
something something something schwifty3 something

$ echo $mystring | sed -n 's/.*\s*\(schwifty[0-9]\)\s*.*/\1/p'
schwifty3

$ echo $mystring | sed -n 's/.*\s*\(schwifty\)[0-9]\s*.*/\1/p'
schwifty
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in bash.

```
a=" $mystring "      # pad with spaces (in-case the word is first or last)
a="${a#* schwifty}"  # chop all before and including schwifty
a="schwifty${a%% *}" # restore schwifty chop all after first word, 
echo "$a"
```